# List to dictionary conversion using {} and dict() differs?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have been trying to convert a list with even indices as strings (names) and odd ones as integers (phone numbers). These values are read from the user in the form:
namenumber

so I did this:

```
my_dict = {input().strip().split() for _ in range(3)} 
but this gives an error:

unhashable type: 'list'
```

- Here, I got my mistake. I am trying to make a list as a set item. Not possible. (Courtesy of [Klaus_D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3929826/klaus-d))

However, this works:

```
my_dict = dict(input().strip().split() for _ in range(cases))---- CASE:1
```

and I get my_dict as:

```
{name1:phone1, name2:phone2......}
```

Also, this works fine as well:

```
my_dict= dict([input().split() for _ in range(3)]) ----CASE:2
```

Why eliminating the square brackets makes no effect in the first case?

So I conclude that my understanding of input().strip().split() is wrong here. So, this is where I am looking for a suggestion.

Thanks!

[PS: This is an edited version, but much related to the previous one]

Comment: You are using a set comprehension, not a dictionary comprehension.

Comment: the two sub expressions are quite different, one is a generator while the other is a list comprehension - but in both cases you are passing to `dict` an iterable whose items are themselves iterables with exactly two items, so you end up with the same dictionary

Comment: @gimix,  Got it. Thanks!